# My computer is scanning ports 21, 80 etc in my neighbour computers, and being scanned thoroughly by another computer in the network

Tags: networking, port

Checking the Traffic log of Symantec Endpoint Protection in another computer I noticed that my computer had scanned its ports 21, 80, 8080 and 4899 (using random local ports). In this image, 42.51 is my computer and is scanning 42.182, where the log is taken from (24-Jul-18)

[image]

Is this normal behavior, or should I check my computer ?

EDIT 2. It happens daily it seems (26-jul-18). Same ports (21, 80, 8080, 4899)

[image]

EDIT. Symantec in my computer (42.51) also blocked traffic from 42.238 this morning, and this is the log :

[image]

A. Is this is somehow normal ?

B. Is the user in 42.238 willingly scanning my computer ?

C. Is it some malicious software ?

I guess there is no practical way to differentiate between B. and C. Mostly I would like to know if this is normal..

Comment: Honestly, with properly functioning Endpoint protection, the question of "is it malware" is *usually* no... Have you tried Malwarebytes or a similar product scan?

Comment: Malwarebytes scan came basically clean (one PUP and one MachineLearning/Anomalous.100% in Downloads) so that leaves a voluntary port scan by the user. But he isn't supposed to have the knowledge to do that although it's his MAC. Also idk if something like nmap would scan four times port 10554 from different local ports like you can see in the log. (There is the same repetition with ports 20, 21, 22, 23, 110 etc). This is still a mystery to me..

Answer (score 1):

on the machine that was scanned, refer to the following steps.
1. run the **CMD** as administrator
2. run the command **netstat -ano** to find those port that are scanned.
3. or run netstat **-ano | find "20"**  (or other port number)
4. we can see that at the end of every line there is a number, this is **process ID**, remember them  [image] 
5. Then open **task manager**, click **Details**
6. you will see what programs or services they are used on the ports  [image]
7. If the programs or services are normally and should be scanned by you computer, it is normally

Comment: hi, nice idea, but the computer being scanned (I assume you mean 42.182 in the first part of the question) has no apps listening on those ports. It was just being scanned by my computer on ports 21 (ftp server), 80, 8080 (http server) and 4899 (radmin server). I followed your approach and there were no connections on those ports